# hosting an old part of a php site on a subdomain?

Tags: php, html, web, subdomain, hosting

This is my first post here, I'm also kinda new to web dev.
I made a new site for a client an changed the hosting of the domain.

But he wants an old part of the side witch is an catalog with sorting functions made with php behind a login. I want to host this on a subsite of the hosting. Can I "copy-paste" this catalog with ftp? i have a copy of the database and the full file of the old website. I know that the php version is out of date and I'm having trouble how to find a way to update this.

When i upload the site i get a permission error trying to visit it.
When I try it locally i get to the login screen and the first page of the catalog, but when i try to select a category I only get a white screen.

I already want to thank you all for the help.

Comment: I only can help you with permission: If you want to execute a php file you have to set execute checked on the file property in your ftp folder. Chmod in linux if I'm right.

Comment: To anybody who was wondering and reading this question. I solved this by changing the php code from the catalog where syntaxes read mysql. I googled my way into it and come to the conclusion that the new syntax was mySqli. Changed this manually in all files and managed to get the catalog hosted on a subdomain.